# Setting a dynamic height of DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, code-behind

Here's what I have:

```
OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand();
cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd3.CommandText = "SP_LPI_REGISTER_CLAIM_LIST";
cmd3.Connection = conn;

cmd3.Parameters.Add("vClaim_Number", OracleType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtClaimSearch.Text;
cmd3.Parameters.Add("vClaimList", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

//connection2.Open();

var SearchAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd3);
var ds = new DataTable();
SearchAdapter.Fill(ds);

ds.Columns[0].SetOrdinal(1);
ds.Columns[1].SetOrdinal(2);
ds.Columns[2].SetOrdinal(3);
ds.Columns[3].SetOrdinal(4);
ds.Columns[4].SetOrdinal(5);
ds.Columns[5].SetOrdinal(6);

DataGrid_ClaimSearch.DataSource = ds;
DataGrid_ClaimSearch.DataBind();

DataGrid_ClaimSearch.Columns[7].Visible = false;

// The trouble starts here
var height = 40;
foreach (DataGridRow dr in DataGrid_ClaimSearch.Rows)
{
    height += dr.Height;
}

DataGrid_ClaimSearch.Height = height;
```

The last few lines are more-or-less "air code".  There's no `Rows` available for DataGrid_ClaimsSearch.  Can someone tell me the proper way to achieve my desired result, which would be to have the height of the DataGrid set dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out, but it's not very elegant.  If anyone knows of a better way to do this, please post an answer and I'll be happy to give you a checkmark if it works.

What I did was after I fill the DataTable, I check to see how many rows there are:

```
SearchAdapter.Fill(ds);
int DRC = ds.Rows.Count;
```

Then, after the DataBind, I set the height based on a static number (50), the approximate height of the rows(15), and the number of records in the DataTable:

```
DataGrid_ClaimSearch.DataBind();

DataGrid_ClaimSearch.Columns[7].Visible = false;

var height = 50 + (15*DRC);
DataGrid_ClaimSearch.Height = height;
```

Also, on the ASPX side, I removed the Height parameter because it was overriding the height my code was trying to set.  I also had to add a page tag to the ASPX side (`<p>`) because the objects beneath my GridView were too close to the bottom of the GridView.

Like I said, it worked fine but I gotta believe there's a more elegant way to do it.